# javascript create array of objects with a fixed length based on another bigger array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given an array of an even length:

```
const items = [
  'this/is/path1',
  'this/is/path2',
  'this/is/path3',
  'this/is/path4',
  'this/is/path5',
  'this/is/path6'
];
```

i want to create an array of objects that will have certain length `objnb`.
Based on this length, i will divide the above `items` into chunks, and then store the first index on a new object property `path`, and the following elements in `other1`, `other2`; The same for the other object chunks.

My solution is hacky:

```
const objnb = 2;
const other1 = true;
const other2 = true;
const outputobjs = items.length / objnb;
const result = items.map((entry, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  console.log({ entry, index })
  if (index % outputobjs === 0) {
    obj.path = entry;
    obj.others = {};
    if (other1) {
      obj.others.two = items[index + 1];
    }
    if (other2) {
      obj.others.three = items[index + 2];
    }

    return obj;
  }

  return obj;
})


console.log('result: ', result)
```

the output is correct:

```
[ { path: 'this/is/path1',
    others: { two: 'this/is/path2', three: 'this/is/path3' } },
  {},
  {},
  { path: 'this/is/path4',
    others: { two: 'this/is/path5', three: 'this/is/path6' } },
  {},
  {} ]
```

but unfortunately, i get empty objects, which i don't want.
How can i achieve the same with much cleaner way?

the preferred result will not contain the empty objects.

### update

another example is:

```
const items = [
  'this/is/path1',
  'this/is/path2',
  'this/is/path3',
  'this/is/path4'
];

const objnb = 2;
const other1 = true;
const other2 = false;
const outputobjs = items.length / objnb;
const result = items.map((entry, index) => {
  let obj = {};
  console.log({ entry, index })
  if (index % outputobjs === 0) {
    obj.path = entry;
    obj.others = {};
    if (other1) {
      obj.others.two = items[index + 1];
    }
    if (other2) {
      obj.others.three = items[index + 2];
    }

    return obj;
  }

  return obj;
})


console.log('result: ', result)
```

and result is:

```
[ { path: 'this/is/path1', others: { two: 'this/is/path2' } },
  {},
  { path: 'this/is/path3', others: { two: 'this/is/path4' } },
  {} ]
```

### clarification:

every object in the new array will be alike, for example, they will all have `path`, and since we are dividing the original array evenly, the new objects will have all the same properties. For example, if one has `two`, the rest of the objects in the new array will all have this property, and if they are supposed to have `three`, they all will have that property.

the new object will look like:

```
{ path: 'this/is/path1',
    others: { 
       two: 'this/is/path2', 
       three: 'this/is/path3' // optional; if one object has this, others must have it too.
    }
}
```

so basically, by dividing the original items array into a specific number, either 2, 3, 4, etc... we will chunk it into smaller arrays, and the new object `path` will be `chunkedArray[0]`, and if there is one more item in this new chunked array, then `two` will be `chunkedArray[1]`, and if still one more left, then `three` will be `chunkedArray[2]`

so if we divide it by 2, then we will have:

```
const chunkedArray1 = [
  'this/is/path1', // path
  'this/is/path2', //others.two
  'this/is/path3' //others.three
];

const chunkedArray2 = [
  'this/is/path4',// path
  'this/is/path5',//others.two
  'this/is/path6'//others.three
];
```

therefore the new objects will have `two` and `three`;

but if we divide it into 3, we will have:

```
const chunkedArray1 = [
  'this/is/path1',// path
  'this/is/path2'//others.two
];

const chunkedArray2 = [
  'this/is/path3',// path
  'this/is/path4'//others.two
];

const chunkedArray3 = [
  'this/is/path5',// path
  'this/is/path6'//others.two
];
```

so we will have only path and `two` for each object.

every new chunkedArray will have at least length of two, meaning that path and `two` is present in every new object.

### another example:

and one basic example is, if the original array is three, then we can't divide it evenly to smaller chunks, so :

```
const items = [
  'this/is/path1', //path
  'this/is/path2',//others.two
  'this/is/path3'//others.three
];
```

and same here , if the original array is two length:

```
const items = [
  'this/is/path1', //path
  'this/is/path2',//others.two
];
```

Comment: does it have to be `others.two, others.three`... Or could it be `others._2, others._3..` ?

Comment: @Logar actually i have a particular key name, that will be something like `others[two]` and `const two = '2a'`, for example, and `const three = '3a'`

Comment: okay, my question was basically, can we use an 'index like' to generate the keys or do they have to be set manually ?

Comment: i have specific key names, and i have to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one solution which uses `reduce`.

```js
const items = [
  'this/is/path1',
  'this/is/path2',
  'this/is/path3',
  'this/is/path4',
  'this/is/path5',
  'this/is/path6'
]

function splitItems(data, chunkSize) {
  if (chunkSize < 2) return data // or the special value you'd like.
  const labels = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
    4: 'four'
    // ... others
  }
  return data.reduce((pre, cur, index) => {
    if (index % chunkSize === 0) {
      /* for old question
      pre.push({
        path: cur,
        others: {}
      })*/
      let newItem = {
        path: cur,
        others: {}
      }
      Array.from(Array(chunkSize-1).keys()).map( itemIndex => {
        newItem.others[labels[(itemIndex+1) % chunkSize + 1]] = '' //or other default valu
      })
      pre.push(newItem)
    }
    else {
      pre[pre.length - 1].others[labels[index % chunkSize + 1]] = items[index]
    }
    return pre
  }, [])
}

console.log('@Test Case 1@', splitItems(items, 2), '@@')
console.log('@Test Case 2@', splitItems(items.slice(0, 2), 2), '@@')
console.log('@Test Case 3@', splitItems(items.slice(0, 4), 2), '@@')
console.log('@Test Case 4@', splitItems(items.slice(0, 5), 3), '@@')

// calc the size first, then exec splitItems
function splitByLength(data, numberOfChunks) {
  let chunkSize = Math.round(data.length/3, 0)
  return splitItems(data, chunkSize)
}
console.log('@Test Case 5@', splitByLength(items.slice(0, 5), 3), '@@')
```

Comment: i think there is a bit of misunderstanding, i clarified it in the question

Comment: it is working as expected, but i would prefer the chunkSize you are passing in the argument to represent the number of objects in the new array.

Comment: i added another clarification if the original items is of length 2 or 3.

Comment: it is easy, just calcuate the chunkSize first, then execute `function=splitItems`, for your last question, just add one if statement to do the special process.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can loop every 3th item and push it as an object.

```js
const items = [
  'this/is/path1',
  'this/is/path2',
  'this/is/path3',
  'this/is/path4',
  'this/is/path5',
  'this/is/path6'
];
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    if(i%3==0){
      result.push({
          path: items[i],
          others: {two: items[i+1] || null, three: items[i+2] || null}
      })
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: this will only work for the given example. please see the other example i included in the post.

Comment: i think there is a bit of misunderstanding, i clarified it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using reduce, a bit different from @sphinx answer, although quite similar :

```
const objnb = 3;
const otherKeys = ['two', 'three'];

const items = [
  'this/is/path1',
  'this/is/path2',
  'this/is/path3',
  'this/is/path4',
  'this/is/path5',
  'this/is/path6'
];

const outputobjs = Math.ceil(items.length / objnb);

const ar = items.reduce((memo, item, index) => {
  const mod = index % outputobjs
  if(mod === 0)
    memo.push({path: item, others: {}});
  else if(mod <= otherKeys.length)
    Object.assign(memo[memo.length - 1].others, {[otherKeys[mod -1]]: item});
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(ar);
```

Comment: i think there is a bit of misunderstanding, i clarified it in the question

Comment: @storis not sure I got you right, The only worry you had with my answer was that you wanted to divide items into `objnb`  different chunks and not into chunks of `objnb` length ? If so, I just reused your `outputobjs` and it works